# Merge 2 json files with jsonmerge

Tags: python, json

I want to merge many JSON files with the same nested structure, using `jsonmerge`, but have been unsuccessful so far. For example, I want to merge `base` and `head`:

```
base = {
  "data": [
    {
      "author_id": "id1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "author_id": "id2",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "user1",
        "name": "user1"
      },
      {
        "id": "user2",
        "name": "user2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
head = {
  "data": [
    {
      "author_id": "id3",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "author_id": "id4",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "user3",
        "name": "user3"
      },
      {
        "id": "user4",
        "name": "user4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The resulting JSON should be:

```
final_result = {
  "data": [
    {
      "author_id": "id1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "author_id": "id2",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "author_id": "id3",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "author_id": "id4",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "user1",
        "name": "user1"
      },
      {
        "id": "user2",
        "name": "user2"
      },
      {
        "id": "user3",
        "name": "user3"
      },
      {
        "id": "user4",
        "name": "user4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I've only managed to merge correctly the `data` fields, while for `users` it doesn't seem to work. This is my code:

```
from jsonmerge import merge
from jsonmerge import Merger

schema = { "properties": {
                 "data": {
                     "mergeStrategy": "append"
                 },
                 "includes": {
                     "users": {
                        "mergeStrategy": "append"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

merger = Merger(schema)
result = merger.merge(base, head)
```

The end result is:

```
{'data': [{'author_id': 'id1', 'id': '1'},
  {'author_id': 'id2', 'id': '2'},
  {'author_id': 'id3', 'id': '3'},
  {'author_id': 'id4', 'id': '4'}],
 'includes': {'users': [{'id': 'user3', 'name': 'user3'},
   {'id': 'user4', 'name': 'user4'}]}}
```

The issue is with the definition of the `schema`, but I do not know if it is possible to do it like that with `jsonmerge`. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on [jsonschema](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html). So when you have an object within an object (e.g. "users" within "includes") then you'll need to tell jsonschema it is dealing with another object like so:

```json
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "mergeStrategy": "append"
        },
        "includes": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "users": {
                    "mergeStrategy": "append"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this also happens for your top-level objects, hence you have `"properties"` argument on the highest level.